# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [120, 180]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = pd.read_csv('https://stepik.org/media/attachments/course/4852/songs.csv')
X = data[['genre']]
X = pd.get_dummies(X)
y = data.artist
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.50, random_state=42)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
precision = precision_score(predictions, y_test, average='micro')
```

Из-за чего появляется ошибка:

> ```
> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [120, 180]
> ```

В `Jupyter Notebook` всё проходит, но, когда закидываю на сайт курса, который прохожу, появляется данная ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно данная ошибка возникает в том случае когда число экземпляров в `X` не совпадает с числом экземпляров в `Y` при вызове `train_test_split`.

Вот пример:

```
In [11]: X.shape
Out[11]: (360, 3)            #   <--- число экземпляров 360

In [12]: y2 = y.iloc[10:]

In [13]: y.shape
Out[13]: (360,)

In [14]: y2.shape
Out[14]: (350,)              #   <--- число экземпляров 350

In [15]: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y2, test_size=0.50, random_state=42)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [360, 350]
```

PS чтобы понять почему ошибка появляется только при работе "автогрейдера" (автоматический проверяльщик в онлайн курсах) нужно больше информации. Не помешало бы привести условие задачи...

Comment: я проверил через "shape". И там, и там (180, )

Comment: @IvanPetrov, ошибка говорит, что в `X` - 120 строк...